# How to fix iCloud Outlook calendar pasting?

Tags: icloud, ms-office, windows

I have a client that has Outlook 2007 on Windows 7. He's unable to right click and paste into the notes section of an appointment (the contextual menu doesn't even appear). I've seen other people having this issue on the Apple support forums and the Microsoft support forums, but no one has posted a resolution. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Drag the appointment into the My Calendars folder, then edit it and add notes, etc.  Then drag it back to the icloud folder.  Additions will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Apple made al meetings *read-only* to prevent iCloud from resending meeting invitations. Doing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> should paste, though.

There is, too, a *Wibbly-Wobbly* workaround for meetings:

1. On the meeting, click *Forward* and *Forward* (from the displayed menu). Outlook will then tell you that you can't forward the item and will offer to make a copy in your default calendar.
2. Choose *Yes* and *A new message with the appointed attached notes.*
3. Close the forward message **without** sending.
4. Click on the *Move to iCloud*. Doing this will create a **duplicate** but editable appointment in the iCloud folder.
5. Delete the **original** appointment.